# is there something which i forgot to excert in my codes?

Tags: python, syntax-error

i wrote a app which takes the inputs from users and if it is matched to what i have selected runs the rest but if it is not say something to user and exit the app but i do not know why this error appear?!
i used the exit at the end of my codes to finish the app completely but this error which shown in pic every time appear

[image]

```py
while True:
    username=input('please enter your username : \n')
    password=int(input('please enter your password : \n'))
    if username=='mohammad parsa rezaifar' and password==13801380:
        print('congrats :) , you entered')
    else:
        print('username or password is not matched :(')
        exit()
```

Comment: What error are you getting? I don't see an error in the screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Use `break` instead of `exit()`

`break` exits a `for`/`while` loop